# Eclipse: Is a Tomcat Project checkbox won't stick (Java/Camel project)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I just started at a company and inherited 3 projects, all should run under Tomcat. Two of them I can run, but for one of them the checkbox "Is a Tomcat Project" won't stay true. I try to set it and if I check it later, it is unchecked.

This is the dialog (project properties), where I am trying to set Tomcat Project to true, but save/apply doesn't work.

[image: Project properties dialog]

There is no indication as to why it won't stay checked. What to look at/fix?

Update: I see some articles that say to add Tomcat under Preferences/Server/Runtime Environments, except:

1. Tomcat isn't listed
2. Tomcat works for my other two projects.
   Bizarre.

Comment: A tomcat runtime must be configured in eclipse AND I would suggest to fill Context name in.

Comment: Tomcat works for my other two projects, so it is obviously configured. And the working projects don't have a Context name.

Comment: Where is `"Is a Tomcat Project"` in preferences? Is it a tomcat plugin?

Comment: Window Preferences, Tomcat. Perhaps it is there because I added the plug-in. New to Eclipse.

Comment: Apparently you installed the _"Tomcat plugin"_. A more commonly used plugin is the _"JST Server Adapters Extensions (Tomcat)"_ from the WebTools project (available from Eclipse's official releases, Help > Install New Software...)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best answer but anyway:

I got a fresh copy of the project from our repo, did a maven package install, then I checked the above 'Is a Tomcat Project' and it when I right click the project the Tomcat menu is there.